# How to filter sequence of events in a row with RxJava by its value

Tags: rx-java2

I'm producing a stream of events with rxjava2 like this.

```
Observable<Integer> observable = booleanPublisher.map(aBoolean -> {
        if(aBoolean){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }).buffer(4).map( aLilst ->{
        int sum = 0;
        for (Integer i: aLilst) {
            sum +=i;
        }
        return sum;
    });
    observable.subscribe(
            aInt ->{
                Log.v("Value",String.valueOf(aInt));
            }
    );
```

This produces a stream of int events with  values from 0..4, Now I'd like to filter this stream emitting an event when for example 2 integer events in a row are less than 4, and another event when there are 10 integer events in a row that has 4 value. I'm trying to separate in 2 different observables and merging, but had no luck because those 2 events have to reset each other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option for avoiding to use two different subscriptions, is to use `merge`, in this way:

```
enum MatchResult{
    TWO_ITEM_SMALL,
    FIVE_CONSECUTIVE
}


Observable<MatchResult> getObservable1(Observable<Integer> observable) {
        return observable
                .scan(0, (integer, integer2) -> {
                    if (integer2 < 4) {
                        return integer + 1;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }).filter(integer -> integer >= 2)
                .map(integer -> MatchResult.TWO_ITEM_SMALL);
    }

Observable<MatchResult> getObservable2(Observable<Integer> observable) {
    return observable
            .scan(0, (integer, integer2) -> {
                if (integer2 == 4) {
                    return integer + 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }).filter(integer -> integer >= 5)
            .map(integer -> MatchResult.FIVE_CONSECUTIVE);
    }


Observable.merge(getObservable1(getSoruce()), getObservable2(getSoruce()))
            .subscribe(matchResult -> {
                if(matchResult == MatchResult.TWO_ITEM_SMALL) {
                    logd("two items in a row, smaller than 4.");
                } else {
                    logd("five items in a row equals to 4");
                }
            });
```

Comment: I added this as new answer because it uses a different approach and I didn't want to make the other answer too long.

Answer (score 0):

One way for achieving it is to use the `scan` operator. As the documentation says:

> The Scan operator applies a function to the first item emitted by the
>   source Observable and then emits the result of that function as its
>   own first emission.

As returned value from the function you can have the number of items in a row that matches your condition.

I think there is a way for doing it in a single subscription, but I think is more clear to split it, using a `ConnectableObservable` through the `publish()` operator. Let's take this example:

```
Observable<Integer> getSource() {
    return Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2);
}
```

Now we create the observer that checks for the two consecutive small than 4 items.

```
Observable<Integer> source = getSource();

source.scan(0, (integer, integer2) -> {
    if (integer2 < 4) {
        return integer + 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }).filter(integer -> integer >= 2)
    .subscribe(integer -> logd("two items in a row, smaller than 4."));
```

And the subscriber that receives the events for five (in order to simplify) consecutive values equals to 4.

```
source.scan(0, (integer, integer2) -> {
    if (integer2 == 4) {
        return integer + 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }).filter(integer -> integer >= 5) // for you it will be ten
    .subscribe(integer -> logd("five items in a row equals to 4."));
```

And now you just call:

```
observable.connect();
```

**NOTE**: The current implementation doesn't reset the counter when the condition is matched. This means that, for example, that if you are looking for a sequence of five consecutive values equals to 4 this sequence:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4
```

will generate TWO matches, because the first match is with the first five items of the sequence, but then, when you receive a new item with value 4, you still have a match.

Comment: Reseting itself is not nedded, but for example the sequence 444444344 should emit only the 2  matches corresponding to the sequence of 6 4s